# Simplyfing rule to ban by IP mask in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website I'm using this code in `.htaccess`, to ban some addresses:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^159\.138
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^114\.119\.1
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^185\.191\.171
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

I've tried to write it as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^159\.138
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^114\.119\.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^185\.191\.171
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

But this crashes, and doesn't work. How can I merge those rules, so I don't need to write 3 lines for every IP ?

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** with-in single shot to check all IPs together try following. Online demo of regex is: [Online demo of tested regex](https://regex101.com/r/h1vRx5/1)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^((159\.138)|(114\.119\.1)|(185\.191\.171))$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution(conventional method):*** Could you please try changing your Rules to following once, based on your shown samples only. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^159\.138 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^114\.119\.1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^185\.191\.171
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

***NOTE:*** Make sure either you use either of the rules at a time only.